# Correcting my sub-optimal binary search

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, optimization

My binary search is for finding a position for ordered insertion in a `std::vector`.  However, it seems to me that it is performing one (or more?) too many comparisons to find that position.  Particularly the ternary at the end.  Have I designed this wrong?  To be clear, I haven't noticed any errors in output.

```
template<typename T>
size_t find(std::vector<T> data, T value) //returns position value should be inserted at
{
 size_t start = 0;
 size_t end = data.size();

 if (!end) return 0;

 size_t diff;

 while (diff = (end - start) / 2)
 {
  size_t mid = diff + start;

  if (data[mid].value <= value)
  {
   start = mid;
  }
  else
  {
   end = mid;
  }
 }

 return data[start].value <= value ? end : start;
}
```

Comment: `(end - start) >> 1` for the love of God, why?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Obfuscation. It seems to be an in thing.

Comment: @JamesKanze I just like bit shifts ok :( For me it isn't obfuscation, but I'll change it for readability.

Comment: do you want to implement `std::upper_bound()`?

Comment: Your code is complicated. Look here: http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/search/binary_search_iterative. Also, you say you notice no errors in output: what's the returned value when the element you seek is not in the vector? Because you shoudl not return a valid index for non-existing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a binary search, you fundamentally have a three-way branch:
`>`, `<` and `=`.  There's no way of writing this in C++ without
two comparison operators, but I would expect any decent compiler
to optimize them into a single machine instruction for the
comparison, followed by two conditional branches on the results.